# XmlSearch does not recognize xPath

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I have an xml document like so

```
<cfxml variable="mydoc">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Feed xmlns="http://www.example.com/xs/PRR/SyndicationFeed/4.9" name="Test">
        <Product id="test1" removed="false">
            <Source>Widget</Source>
            <ExternalId>Widget01</ExternalId>
            <Name>iWidget 3G</Name>
            <NumReviews>11</NumReviews>
        </product>
    </Feed>
</cfxml>
```

I want to return the `NumReviews` node text. However:

`numReviews = XmlSearch(mydoc, "/Feed/Product/NumReviews");` returns an empty array.

While `numReviews = XmlSearch(myDoc, "//*[local-name()='NumReviews']");` returns the node text.

As far as I can tell, the first line of code is correct and should return the value of NumReviews. Why is it instead returning an empty array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And it may be the name spaces. I think your second syntax is required when namespaces are involved. I know I've had to use it myself.

Answer (score 6):

Something like `numReviews = XmlSearch(mydoc, "/:Feed/:Product/:NumReviews");` also should work when there are namespaces.

Comment: +1 Great tip. I just recently found out about that little known gem myself. Do not know how I missed it all this time..

Comment: Just so no one else beats their head against a wall on this, it looks like this "feature" stopped working in CF9. Here's the issue in the CF tracker: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-3317598

Answer (score 0):

You are using backslashes in the first example. They should be frontslashes, right?

Comment: Oops. That was a typo in the question. Edited.